# Selenium command to wait for loading dynamic values

Tags: ajax, selenium

Sir,
  I am new to selenium. I had recorded the page input and I stuck while running this. In my web page, City Name is in suggestion box. State and country will load against city selection using AJAX.

For me, error occurs at the suggestion place where city is suggested but state and country is not loading.

Note : I am using Selenium IDE. I have tried the commands
1. WaitForElementPresent
2. WaitForValue
3. WaitForText. But still the error exists.

How to fix it.

Comment: http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits

Comment: Can you send the website link?

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Answer (score 0):

One Suggestion i would recommend is to wait for the option tag to be loaded in the target select box.
A combo box is containing `<option>` tags to contain the values within.
Ex:

`<Select>
<Option>Chicago</Option>
<Option>New York</Option>
</Select>`

You can wait for the option tag with the expected value to be present.

```
//Select/option[contains(text(),'Chicago')]
```